# Multi-process pgbouncer pooling: out of available connections

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

My setup:
`postgresql.conf: max_connections = 100`

pgbouncer config:

```
[databases]
markets_parser = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=markets_parser user=argon

datestyle=ISO connect_query='SELECT 1'

[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
listen_port = 6432

unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql

auth_type = trust
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = postgres
pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL

max_client_conn = 90

default_pool_size = 70
min_pool_size = 20

reserve_pool_size = 10
```

I use it from django application (not just site application, but also highload multithreading parsing mechanism) with a bunch of django management commands (which runs as a separate processes), and it works fine (though, *almost* always, not when I have a sudden splash of activity) when I run only one command in time, and raises a lot of 'not enough connections' errors when I run two commands at once.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely increase `max_client_conn` to a higher number. That is the total number of clients that can connect **to** `pgbouncer`, not to the `PostgreSQL` server. It can be as high as you want, for example 2000 or even higher.

That is indeed one of the main purposes of a connection pooler - to hold small amount of connections open to the database, while allowing high number of end client connections to the pooler itself.

The important thing is to set `default_pool_size` not higher than the `max_connections` setting in the `postgresql.conf` file.

Comment: sorry, sir, where is this stated in the pgbouncer docs maybe?